# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' cannot figure out error

Tags: python, split, attributes, append, jupyter

The question is to keep asking a person to say their favorite websites and stops after they type done. We want to extract the "www." and ".com" and appends that part to a list and finally print the list. I can't figure out what im doing wrong.

```
myweb=[]
while True:
    mywebsite=input("what is your favorite website?")
    if mywebsite=="done":
        print(myweb)
        break
    else:
        myweb.append(mywebsite)
        continue
mywebsite=mywebsite.split('www.')
mywebsite=mywebsite.split('.com')
print(mywebsite)
```

Comment: ```list``` object has no attribute ```split```, did you mean ```str``` object

Comment: what do you mean by extract? do you just want the name?

Comment: mywebsite is a list.... you should iterate throught the content and then apply split

Comment: i just want the name of the website i want to delete the www. and the .com when the user enters that in

Comment: i dont want to ```str``` and i get that list has no attribute but i just want to be able to figure out how to turn the list of websites that the user will type into a list which lists each website they just typed out without the www. and .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using regular expressions. However it looks like you are new to python. So the following corrected code might help you out.

```
myweb_name=[]
while True:
    mywebsite=input("what is your favorite website?")
    if mywebsite=="done":
        break
    else:
        myweb_name.append(mywebsite.split('www.')[1] # remove the www part
                        .split('.com')[0]) # remove the .com part
        continue
print(myweb_name)
```

Comment: @Daj The reason why you were getting the AttributeError in the original code is that at line 10, you assigned the result returned by the `split()` method (which is a list) back to `mywebsite`. Since list does not have a method named split you got an errror at line no 11.

Answer (score 0):

based on your question, i make this function

```
myweb=[]
while True:
    mywebsite=input("what is your favorite website?")
    if mywebsite=="done":
        print(myweb)
        break
    else:
        myweb.append(mywebsite)
        continue

# allocating enough space
mywebsite = [0]*len(myweb)

# extract it
for i in range(len(myweb)):
    # split based on www.domain.com
    mywebsite[i] = myweb[i].split('.')[1]

print(mywebsite)
```

Comment: so that works except it now names the websites they typed into the list as well so it doubles the list. it comes out as this: what is your favorite website?www.twitter.com
what is your favorite website?www.facebook.com
what is your favorite website?done
['www.twitter.com', 'www.facebook.com']
['twitter', 'facebook']

Comment: @J.M.C. now it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use regex on each item in your list

```
>>> import re
>>> website = 'www.amazon.com'
>>> website = re.search('www\.(.*)\.com',website).group(1)
>>> website
'amazon'
```

Answer (score 0):

if all the input 's pattern is www.SOME_WEB_SITES.com, so you can use

```
websites = [ '.'.join(x.split('.')[1:-1]) for x in a]
```

Think about the subdomain cases too, for example:

[www.a.com](http://www.a.com) --> a

[www.a.b.com](http://www.a.b.com) --> a.b

```
x.split('.')[1:-1] # we will get an array ["a","b"]
'.'.join(....) # we need to join them by .
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a python strings `.strip()` function to do this.

```
myweb=[]
while True:
    mywebsite=input("what is your favorite website?")
    if mywebsite=="done":
        for x in myweb:
            print(x.strip("www." + ".com")) #Strips www. and .com from the string.
        break
    else:
        myweb.append(mywebsite)
```